# Show excerpt function in sidebar widget doesnt work in post and pages

Tags: tabs, widget, sidebar

I added showing excerpt code in a tab widget at sidebar. It does only work in the main page. While I go to post pages and other pages, the sidebar widget doesn't work in those pages.

"Read More" can be shown properly at main page sidebar. But they doesn't show at the other pages.

my blog: [www.smehub.com.hk](http://www.smehub.com.hk)

The code I added in tabs_widget.php :

```
<span class="block-meta"><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?>, <?php comments_popup_link(); ?></span><p><?php echo string_limit_words(get_the_excerpt(), 34); ?></p><a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' title='<?php the_title(); ?>' class="readmore"><?php _e('Read More'); ?> <span class="block-arrows">&raquo;</span></a>
```

Thanks alot!